# Reference request for Modular representation theory

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, modules

I am trying to learn modular representation theory.

I would be thankful if any one tell me a good reference to start with?

Comment: What do you know already?

Comment: I am beginner in the modular representation theory you can say nothing. However, I am familiar with the complex representation theory of symmetric groups.

Answer (score 1):

David Benson has two volumes which are aimed at cohomology (and cohomology is only interesting in the modular case).  Volume 1 is [here](http://books.google.com/books/about/Representations_and_Cohomology_Volume_1.html?id=cezF63340GAC), I trust you can find the second.  Also there's a book by Alperin which is pretty good, you can find that [here](http://books.google.com/books/about/Local_Representation_Theory.html?id=p7ylsZUmK3MC).

Comment: Thank you very much to be honest I haven't seen the second book before.